# How to Account for White Space and Append Strings in Double Quotes in Bash Script

Tags: bash, openstack

Hi so I have a task whereby which I need to move over projects from one cluster to another.
The only way I can do that is if I re-create the projects. I have a script that works and gathers the listed projects within a running OpenStack cluster, but I need to be able to take the file I store out and use it to re-create the projects.

Here is the script that gathers the available projects:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# ======================================================
# Author: Richard Barrett
# Date Created: 08/05/2021
# Organization: ITAdminInfra
# Purpose: Initialize OpenStack Project Gather Script
# ======================================================

start=`date +%s`
#set -e

# keep track of the last executed command
trap 'last_command=$current_command; current_command=$BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG

# echo an error message before exiting
#trap 'echo "\"${last_command}\" command filed with exit code $?."' EXIT

# EXIT Codes
# ==========
EXIT=1
EXIT_2=2
EXIT_126=126

AUTH=$(source ~/admin-openrc.sh)
OUTPUTDIR="/tmp/openstack_migrations"
OUTPUTFILE="$OUTPUTDIR/projects_listed_names_as_values.txt"

eval $AUTH
echo "======================================================="
echo "              GATHERING PROJECT INFORMATION    "
echo "======================================================="
# Make Directories in $OUTPUTDIR
if [ -d "$OUTPUTDIR" ]; then
  # Take action if $OUTPUTDIR exists
  echo "The Directory $OUTPUTDIR exists..."
  echo "Check for Pre-Existing OpenStack Migration Info..."
else
  echo "Directory $OUTPUTDIR does not exist..."
  echo "Making $OUTPUTDIR for OpenStack Info..."
  mkdir -p $OUTPUTDIR
fi
echo "Sourced Keystone via $AUTH succesful..."
echo "======================================================="
echo "              OPENSTACK PROJECTS COLLECTED     "
echo "======================================================="
openstack project list -c Name -f value
openstack project list -c Name -f value > $OUTPUTFILE
echo "======================================================="
printf "\n"
echo "Information on projects gathered has been stored in $OUTPUTFILE"
```

The `$OUTPUTFILE` holds contents that look like this:

```
[ OpenStack]$ cat /tmp/openstack_migrations/projects_listed_names_as_values.txt
testing_grounds
Michaud
Ansible Automation
Sustaining Development
Data Center Services
MF-DevStack
Kubernetes Labs
mso-ems
Network Development
Data Engineering
Data Center Operations Service Scanning
admin
service
OpenStack-Example
Petes-place
test
Image Factory
Network Automation
Fault and Performance Management
Microseg
Development
Docker Enterprise
Application Architecture
casa-de-pedro
```

Some of the projects have white spaces. However, I thought that with a for loop this would be easy to re-create.

```
for i in $(cat test.txt); do openstack project create $i; done
```

However, this did not work as when I used `$i` it did not account for white space, so essentially any strings that had spaces in between accounted for two strings. This means that when I iterated over it and tried to re-create it, it would take `Ansible Automation` and try to make a project for both `Ansible` and `Automation`. To handle this I can place the strings in double quotes

```
openstack project create "Ansible Automation"
```

This would create the project. How can I account for space within the text file and append my strings inside double quotes using a for-loop in bash?

```
for i in $(cat file.txt); do openstack project create <something with $i that places the string with white space in double quotes "<string>">; done
```

Can someone help me figure out how to account for `"<string1 string2>"`

Comment: [Don't Read Lines with For](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), This ain't python and the likes.

Comment: Something like this then? `while read line; do echo "$line"; done < test.txt`

Comment: See [How can a read file,data,stream line-by-line or field-by-field](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: thanks @Jetchisel that helped me out a lot.

Comment: `eval $AUTH` -- remember `eval` is just one character away from `evil`. That looks a bit sketchy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `mapfile` for an array.

```
mapfile -t prj < file
for p in "${prj[@]}"; do echo "[$p]"; done
```

This should correctly quote your project names.
Extrapolate for your needs.